# Once I make the columns 100 percent of the screen, the contents are aligned on top, instead of the middle

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, grid

I want to set my column of size vh-100
however the moment I add that piece of code, it will shift everything to the top.

How do I go about avoiding this?
Specifically on the left side, the content has image, text1, text2
I want these three items centered on the left column
centered vertically and horizontally

```css
.left-side {
  background-color: #012611;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Monarcha";
  font-weight: bolder;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "Soleil";
}
label {
  font-family: "Monarcha";
}

.right-side {
  background-color: white;
}

div {
  outline: black solid 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.2.1 -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Stack the columns on mobile by making one full-width and the other half-width -->
      <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <!-- Left Column -->
        <div
          class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 vh-100 center-block text-center d-none d-sm-block left-side"
        >
          <img src="../pictures/logo.png" alt="" width="72" height="72" />
          <h1>Text1</h1>
          <h3>Text2</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- Right Column -->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 center-block right-side">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <form class="form-signin">
                  <div class="text-center d-block d-sm-none">
                    <img
                      src="../pictures/logo.png"
                      alt=""
                      width="72"
                      height="72"
                    />
                    <h1>text1</h1>
                    <h3>text2</h3>
                  </div>

                  <h3 class="login-heading mb-4">Login</h3>

                  <!-- Sign In Form -->
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label>Email address</label>
                    <input
                      type="email"
                      class="form-control"
                      id="floatingInput"
                      placeholder="name@example.com"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input
                      type="password"
                      class="form-control"
                      id="floatingPassword"
                      placeholder="Password"
                    />
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-between mb-3">
                    <div>
                      <input
                        class="form-check-input"
                        type="checkbox"
                        value=""
                        id="rememberPasswordCheck"
                      />
                      <label
                        class="form-check-label"
                        for="rememberPasswordCheck"
                      >
                        Remember password
                      </label>
                    </div>

                    <a class="small" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
                  </div>

                  <div class="d-grid">
                    <button
                      class="btn btn-block btn-outline-dark text-uppercase mb-2"
                      type="submit"
                    >
                      Sign in
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-7VPbUDkoPSGFnVtYi0QogXtr74QeVeeIs99Qfg5YCF+TidwNdjvaKZX19NZ/e6oz"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added flex-column align-items-center justify-content-sm-center

```css
.left-side {
  background-color: #012611;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Monarcha";
  font-weight: bolder;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "Soleil";
}
label {
  font-family: "Monarcha";
}

.right-side {
  background-color: white;
}

div {
  outline: black solid 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.2.1 -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Stack the columns on mobile by making one full-width and the other half-width -->
      <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <!-- Left Column -->
        <div
          class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 vh-100 center-block flex-column align-items-center justify-content-sm-center text-center d-none d-sm-flex left-side"
        >
          <img src="../pictures/logo.png" alt="" width="72" height="72" />
          <h1>Text1</h1>
          <h3>Text2</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- Right Column -->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 center-block right-side">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <form class="form-signin">
                  <div class="text-center d-block d-sm-none">
                    <img
                      src="../pictures/logo.png"
                      alt=""
                      width="72"
                      height="72"
                    />
                    <h1>text1</h1>
                    <h3>text2</h3>
                  </div>

                  <h3 class="login-heading mb-4">Login</h3>

                  <!-- Sign In Form -->
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label>Email address</label>
                    <input
                      type="email"
                      class="form-control"
                      id="floatingInput"
                      placeholder="name@example.com"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input
                      type="password"
                      class="form-control"
                      id="floatingPassword"
                      placeholder="Password"
                    />
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-between mb-3">
                    <div>
                      <input
                        class="form-check-input"
                        type="checkbox"
                        value=""
                        id="rememberPasswordCheck"
                      />
                      <label
                        class="form-check-label"
                        for="rememberPasswordCheck"
                      >
                        Remember password
                      </label>
                    </div>

                    <a class="small" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
                  </div>

                  <div class="d-grid">
                    <button
                      class="btn btn-block btn-outline-dark text-uppercase mb-2"
                      type="submit"
                    >
                      Sign in
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-7VPbUDkoPSGFnVtYi0QogXtr74QeVeeIs99Qfg5YCF+TidwNdjvaKZX19NZ/e6oz"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```